# Mapbox --> Is there a way to optimize a route with more than 12 stops?

Tags: mapbox

I guess this question was asked before, but I've tried with different keywords and I wasn't able to find it.

I'm using MapBox Optimize Route API. I an AJAX request to get the best route available, e.g. I call

```
https://api.mapbox.com/optimized-trips/v1/mapbox/driving/-73.6182,45.7129;-73.6585,45.5534;-73.6081,45.5432;-73.6845,45.5449;-73.5821,45.5219;-73.5821,45.5819?source=first&destination=last&roundtrip=false&access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

and it gives me back the best route.

The problem when have more than 12 stops according to this [https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/optimization-api/#:~:text=The%20Mapbox%20Optimization%20API%20returns,between%20up%20to%2012%20coordinates](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/optimization-api/#:%7E:text=The%20Mapbox%20Optimization%20API%20returns,between%20up%20to%2012%20coordinates).

Any idea what's the way to go to be able solve... let's say a 30 stops route?

Thank!
Cheers

Comment: Split into 3 routes of 10

Comment: I need it to be optimized in one batch. I don't see how I could arbitrary split the run in 3. Each one will be optimized for the 10 subgroup, but the whole run will be a real mess. It's much more complicated than that, but let say I have a bunch of 10 people in Montreal, 10 in Toronto and 10 in another city. If I don't pay attention of how I subdivise it, I may have to go 3 times back and forward in each city. Oh, of course I could do something to regroup each subgroup, but I'm sure I can avoid this optimization on my side. That's why I'm using MapBox at the end.

Comment: There must be a parameter missing somewhere when I make the API request.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of 12 waypoints is the default limitation. It can be increased by Mapbox to more than 30, so you can solve your problem. For that you would have to reach out to Mapbox as described here:

https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#optimization-api-restrictions-and-limits

I believe there should not be extra cost involved, only if you exceed the free tier.

Comment: Yes it worked! I've send a request to increase it and after 1 week I didn't had an answer. I've added the mapbox support program (50$ per month) and I had the answer in less than 24h ;) It works like a charm since :D  Thank!!

Comment: @Flydwin what did they bump your limit to?